# Anyone have any examples of simple code for a splashscreen in Java?

Tags: java, splash-screen

Just wondering has anyone any links to basic splash screen code or examples?

Answer (score 5):

In JDK 1.6 you can do the following

```
    java -splash:filename.gif SplashTest
```

See this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/). Alternatively you can extend `JWindow` and make you own splash screen. See this [link](http://www.thatsjava.com/java-swing/18260/).

Answer (score 2):

The Java 6 splash functionality is well worth looking at.

There might also be another way to add a splash (that will work for earlier JREs as well).  If the app. has a GUI and can be launched from a web site, look into [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to launch it.  JWS provides a splash screen ability, as well as many other neat features including desktop integration (menu items & desktop shortcuts with icons) & auto update.